# How to use \theorem?

Tags: theorems

I don't know why this doesn't work:

[image]

I'm a beginner in `LaTeX` and I'm trying a lot to understand this.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Given two line segments whose lengths are $a$ and $b$ respectively there 
  is a real number $r$ such that $b=ra$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
To prove it by contradiction try and assume that the statemenet is false,
proceed from there and at some point you will arrive to a contradiction.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The log:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment theorem undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.8 \begin{theorem}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 9.
```

**Remark 1:** I've installed Texmaker and Texlive with `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

**Remark 2:** My OS is Ubuntu and my latex editor is Texmaker.

**Remark 3** I'm studying using this [site](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Theorems_and_proofs) but I used also the documentation of the package `amsthm`. (in the documentation we should use `lem` instead of lemma command)

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: @Aradnix it's in the picture.

Comment: @user26832: Please add your code as real text, not as an image. Users here hardly can extract it from the image, unless tediously typing int as Aradnix asked of you already.

Comment: Well is a quite difficult to read on my 17" screen. You could copy the code and paste it below your question, if you indent four times or press Ctrl + K you can set the code view. Meanwhile read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems), after read how to create a MWE in the link above, could be useful.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ok, I'll do that.

Comment: @Aradnix is it ok now?

Comment: @user26832 Much better, now you can try the answer below and read the link I shared for understand better how to use mathematical statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) is a package to *create* theorems and theorem-related environments. It does not do this by default. So, you could issue

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

to define the `theorem` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Test
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The detail here is that you have to define previously in your preamble each and every one of the kinds of statements you want to use i.e.a theorem, proof, corollary, lemma, etc.

Comment: it's highly recommended to read the `amsthm` documentation (`texdoc amsthm` if you're on a tex live installation).  it's only 5 pages long, and contains other useful hints.